# How To Break a while loop inside a sensing if condition

Tags: c, arduino, arduino-uno

The essence of my psuedo-code is as follows (I have simplified it to arrange for simpler answers):

```
if (vibrate == 1){ //this is the input sensing to the arduino. 
  //It is either 1 or 0
  //constantly run a while loop IF vibrate ==1
  i=51;
  while(vibrate ==1){
     analogWrite(Motor,i); //constantly outputing a pulse of increasing magnitude
     delay(10); //delay it for a certain period of time
     i=i+50; //increment i 
     if (i>=255){
       i=51;
     }
  }
}
else{ //do something else. Has it's own functions}
```

Now vibrate is coming in from a sensor. If vibrate is 1, I would automatically want to output a ramped pulse (i.e. the while loop). However, if vibrate changes it's value (i.e. goes to zero), I would like the while loop not to be triggered, and if it is triggered, I would like to exit the while loop. The issue that I face is that vibrate updates itself outside of the while loop, and hence i'll get an infinite loop. Is there a better way to incorporate this? I can't update the value of vibrate in the while loop either, since I need to check the greater 'if' too.

Comment: why can you not read vibrate from within the while loop, can you not add if (!vibrate = analogRead(pin)) break; after delay(10); ?

Comment: While you have acted in good faith, pseudocode is the least helpful thing you can do, generally. Please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve. Also you should format your code better because currently it's divided into multiple different sections. Also `if (i > /255)` is probably very wrong.

Comment: @138 interesting, I will try putting that in

Comment: Is this some manner of bit-banging GPIO? Use PWM hardware and your problems will go away.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**update the vibrate variable** within the while loop. You don't need to use **break**

```
void updateVibrate(){
       //UPDATE THE VIBRATE VARIABLE
    }

    if (vibrate == 1){ //this is the input sensing to the arduino. 
      //It is either 1 or 0
      //constantly run a while loop IF vibrate ==1
      i=51;
      while(vibrate ==1){
         analogWrite(Motor,i); //constantly outputing a pulse of increasing magnitude
         delay(10); //delay it for a certain period of time
         i=i+50; //increment i 
         if (i>=255){
           i=51;
         }
       updateVibrate();//Call function which will update the vibrate (Global) Variable
      }
    }
    else{ //do something else. Has it's own functions}
```

Alternatively, when you have fixed number of iterations, you can use for loop with break statement

Answer (score 2):

Inside a loop you could call `break;` to continue execution outside the loop you called it in.

Comment: I think you mean "break; " instead of "break();".

Comment: Yep, that was my first idea to use a break statement, the only thing is the value of the variable 'vibrate' doesn't update in arduino. I'm unsure why, but as soon as it enters the while loop, it won't update till the while loop is done.

Comment: Maybe there's a call you could make to update the value. I don't know arduino.